# loop is not working of jquery function

Tags: jquery

I want slide the images continuously but it's not working it's slides once only images are not repeating again what should i do to correct the code this code works when i am giving image id 1 2 3 but not work for image id
4 5 6 and so on.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function slider2() {
        $(".slider2 #4").show("fade", 500);
        $(".slider2 #4").delay(5500).hide("slide", { direction: "right" }, 500);

        var sc = $(".slider2 img").size();
        var count = 5;

        setInterval(function () {
            $(".slider2 #" + count).show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 500);
            $(".slider2 #" + count).delay(5500).hide("slide", { direction: "right" }, 500);

            if (count == sc) {
                count = 4;
            }
            else {
                count = count + 1;
            }
        }, 6500);
    }
</script>



.slider2
    {
        /*width: 100px;
        height: 100px;*/
        overflow: hidden;
        /*margin: 30px auto;
        background-image: url(images/img.png);
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        background-position: top;*/
    }

        /*.shadow
    {
        background-image: url(images/img.png);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: top;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
    }*/

        .slider2 img
        {
            /*width: 100px;
            height: 100px;*/
            display: none;
        }
<div align="center">
    <asp:Panel runat="server">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td class="slider2">
                    <img id="4" src="3.jpg" height="200" width="200" />
                    <img id="5" src="2.jpg" height="200" width="200" />
                    <img id="6" src="4.jpg" height="200" width="200" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
     </asp:Panel>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've re-written your code to be slightly cleaner and more DRY. This *should* work on your current HTML.

```
function nextSlide (container) {

  // The current slide will always be the only one visible
  // You might want to add animation detection to ensure this
  // if you make it complex
  var current = $('img:visible', container);

  // The function nextAll() gives us all of the img elements
  // that occur after the current
  var next = current.nextAll('img').first();

  // If the current one is the last one, there will be no
  // next img element - so we should check we've got some
  if (next.length<1) {
    // If not, we simply get the first img element
    next = $('img', container).first();
  }

  // Do some show() and hide()
  // You can add complexity here but I've simplified
  // as your main issue appeared to be finding the correct
  // slides to work with
  $(current).hide("fade", 500);
  $(next).show("fade", 500);

}

// It's always a good idea to pass setInterval() to an object.
// That way you can clear it later if needed
slider2interval = {};

// You might consider using a var to pass in the time - as you can
// alter this progamatically, and / or share amongst other sliders etc
slider2time = 3000;

// This is our trigger function where we setInterval
function slider2() {

  // Pick up the containing element so we don't have to keep
  // bogging our script down with selecting known elements
  var container = $(".slider2");

  // Code is cleaner and more DRY if you build a function outside of loops
  // or intervals etc
  slider2interval = setInterval(function () {
    nextSlide(container);
  }, slider2time);

}

// Off we go!
slider2();
```

CSS: Rather than using JS to show() your first slide - just automatically display it using CSS.

```
.slider2 img:first-of-type {
  display: block;
}
```